# Saving several data-attributes to a single variable - If a certain CSS class exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm stuck and could use some help with what I want to accomplish:

When a button is clicked, all data from the data attribute "timebox" gets saved to a single variable. When data is saved, I'd also like to add a "/" as a seperator for each save.

Also, td's without the class "highlighted" should be ignored.

```
<td class="available highlighted" data-timebox="1 1 26-05-2016 8:0"></td> 
<td class="available highlighted" data-timebox="1 1 26-05-2016 8:15"></td> 
<td class="available" data-timebox="1 1 26-05-2016 11:30"></td> 
<td class="available" data-timebox="1 1 26-05-2016 11:45"></td> 
<td class="available" data-timebox="1 1 26-05-2016 12:0"></td>
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this in jQuery? 
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this solution is pretty straightforward. On the button click, simply grab all elements with the highlighted class that also have a data-timebox attribute, append those values to an array, and then join the array with whatever separator you'd like.

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/nejuza/edit?html,js,console,output)**

```
$(function () {
  $("button").on("click", function () {
    var data = [];
    $(".highlighted[data-timebox]").each(function (index, elem){
      data.push($(this).attr("data-timebox"));
    });
    data = data.join("/");
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks for putting your time into this.